# Best practice for implementing indeterminate spinner

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-progressbar

I've been trying many different ways to implement a proper progress spinner during fragment transition. Something like this:

[image]

The main, overarching issue that I am encountering is that the old fragment is still being displayed when the spinner disappears and the (spinner's) background goes transparent. I have tried a few things to no luck, and I feel like I have run out of options. If anyone has way they know how to cleanly do this, please let me know. I would also like to keep the way I am using `add` for the fragments instead of `replace` I am using a DrawerLayout, and here is my layout XML:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.citychurchtulsa.cc.citychurchapp.MainActivity"/>

<!--Only holds progress bar, main container will be for fragment display!!!-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/loadSpinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/subView"
        android:layout="@layout/progress_spinner"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|start"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:dividerHeight="@dimen/divider_height"
    android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent"
    android:indicatorLeft="?
android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemIndicatorLeft"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This I have tried:

- Putting the `ProgressBar` in the `RelativeLayout` and then setting the visibility on, and the `RelativeLayout` background to a color when I need it, and turning visibility off and background to transparent when I don't. Done outside of the extended fragment class.
- Same as above, but done inside the extended fragment class. Tried two different methods here. In one attempt I hide the items in the `onViewCreated`, and the other in the `onStart`.
- Creating an empty fragment which I use just like I commit just like my other fragments, and then go back through the committing of the desired fragment
- Using a `postDelayed` handler, but I don't necessarily like that since all devices are different

Anyway, I feel like I have tried more but off the top of my head I can't think of anything else. I really appreciate any help.

Here is my code for the display/hide of the spinner I have been trying to use:

```
public void enableLoadSpinner(boolean set){
    if(set)
    {
        mainContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        loadSpinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorSecondary);
    }
    else
    {
        mainContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadSpinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        relativeLayout.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the problem! There was a problem with the views regarding the the `ProgressBar` with `FragmentTransaction`!!! Some sort of wierd interaction was happening between the two and so I removed the `FragmentTransaction` and used a custom animation to make the `ProgressBar` dissappear.